# grouping in twos with ng-repeat

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap to format my edit info page for a web app I'm making. I want to display the fields in two columns. I also don't want to hard code each of the fields into the html. So I would like to use ng-repeat to cycle through my fields. Only one problem, I need to specify a row tag to group the two columns together. So every two fields needs to be in a row. Anyone know how to do this? If this was not explained well let me know and I'll clarify for you.

Comment: please paste your html as well so that we can help more appropriately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I once had the same problem

i havent been able to try any thing in angular view , but i got it done with java script

for example you have $scope.items as

```
$scope.items = [{},{},{},{},{},{}];
```

After Grouping You will have

```
 $scope.items = [ [{},{}], [{},{}], [{},{}], [{},{}] ]
```

**Option 1**

```
$scope.items = [{},{},{},{},{},{},{}];
temporary =[];
chunk=2;
for (index=0,i=0,j=$scope.items.length; i<j; i+=chunk,index++) {
    temporary [index]= $scope.items.slice(i,i+chunk);
}
$scope.items =temporary ;
```

**Option 2**

```
  $scope.items = [{},{},{},{},{},{},{}];
  $scope.groupByTwo = function (array)
  {
  var newarray =[];
  index=0;
  newarray[0]=[];
  for(a=0;a<array.length;a++){
    newarray[index].push(array[a]);
    console.log("pushed index "+a+" on array index " + index)
    if(a!=0 && newarray[index].length>=2)
    {

    index++;
    newarray[index]=[];

    }
    }
  return newarray;
}
$scope.items=$scope.groupByTwo($scope.items);
```